# Перевести числа в обычную запись (К и М заменить на нули)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Числа записаны вот так К это 1000, М это 1000000

```
0        110.5M
1           77M
2        118.5M
3           72M
4          102M
          ...  
18202       60K
18203       60K
18204       60K
18205       60K
18206       60K
Name: Value, Length: 18207, dtype: object
```

Как привести к обычным числам весь столбец?

```
def m_k(row):
        if 'M' in row:
            return ((row.str.replace("[^\d\.]", "", regex=True).astype('float'))*1000000)
        elif 'K' in row:
            return ((row.str.replace("[^\d\.]", "", regex=True).astype('float'))*1000)
```

так не получается

Comment: Я ответ написал, но на будущее имейте в виду, что "не получается" - это ни о чём. Если есть ошибка - нужно приводить ошибку. И объяснять, почему вы не можете её сами исправить. Если результат отличается от искомого - нужно приводить искомый результат и получающийся. Ну и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант, переделанный из вашего:

```
import pandas as pd

def m_k(row):
        if 'M' in row:
            return float(row.replace("M", "")) * 1_000_000
        elif 'K' in row:
            return float(row.replace("K", "")) * 1_000

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['4.5M', '600K']})
print(df['data'].apply(m_k))
```

Вывод:

```
0    4500000.0
1     600000.0
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series(['12345', '110.5M', '60.45K', '0.000215G', '0.0006458T'])
suffixes = {None: 1, 'T': 10 ** 12, 'G': 10 ** 9, 'M': 10 ** 6, 'K': 10 ** 3} # Множители для Tera, Giga, Mega, Kilo. None (без суффикса) = 1
s = s.str.extract('([KMGT])')[0].replace(suffixes) * s.str.replace('[KMGT]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
print(s)
```

```
0        12345.0
1    110500000.0
2        60450.0
3       215000.0
4    645800000.0
dtype: float64
```